# Llama Index custom embeddings - difference between getting text embeddings vs query embeddings?

Tags: python, nlp, llama-index

I'm looking here at the Llama index documentation to create custom embeddings: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/embeddings/custom_embeddings.html

I'm confused at the documentation - what's the difference betweeen the two methods `_get_query_embedding()` and `_get_text_embedding`? They look exactly the same to me

```
from typing import Any, List
from InstructorEmbedding import INSTRUCTOR
from llama_index.embeddings.base import BaseEmbedding


class InstructorEmbeddings(BaseEmbedding):
    def __init__(
        self,
        instructor_model_name: str = "hkunlp/instructor-large",
        instruction: str = "Represent the Computer Science documentation or question:",
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        self._model = INSTRUCTOR(instructor_model_name)
        self._instruction = instruction
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def _get_query_embedding(self, query: str) -> List[float]:
            embeddings = self._model.encode([[self._instruction, query]])
            return embeddings[0]

        def _get_text_embedding(self, text: str) -> List[float]:
            embeddings = self._model.encode([[self._instruction, text]])
            return embeddings[0]

        def _get_text_embeddings(self, texts: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
            embeddings = self._model.encode(
                [[self._instruction, text] for text in texts]
            )
            return embeddings
```